# What is this part of a URL called?

Tags: networking, dns, subdomain

I am referring to the string between the last forward slash of the protocol and the next forward slash, for example:

https://**stackoverflow.com**/questions/ask

https://**login.yahoo.com**/?.src=ym&.intl=uk&.lang=en-GB&.done

https://**www.google.com**/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google

What is this part of a url called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how the URL is made up, it's called the host, or the authority.

If you had http://www.stackoverflow.com/MyQuestion, then 'www.stackoverflow.com' would be the host' and authority.

if you had http://www.stackoverflow.com:80/MyQuestion, then 'www.stackoverflow.com' is still the host, but 'www.stackoverflow.com:80' is the authority.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Answer (score 2):

It is called the domain or host.  URI or URL's are the combination of the domain and the query string.

Comment: even if it contains a subdomain? (second case)

Comment: technically, `stackoverflow.com` is a domain (group of hosts) and `www.stackoverflow.com` is one host within that domain, but DNS servers know to route the requests to the default host.

Answer (score 0):

That part is called the **host**. More generally speaking, here are the different parts of a URL, as per [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location). (So at least according to how Javascript calls it)

```
protocol://username:password@hostname:port/pathname?search#hash
-----------------------------href------------------------------
                             -----host----
-----------      origin      -------------
```

- `protocol` - protocol scheme of the URL, including the final ':'
- `hostname` - domain name
- `port` - port number
- `pathname` - *`/pathname`*
- `search` - *`?parameters`*
- `hash` - *`#fragment_identifier`*
- `username` - username specified before the domain name
- `password` - password specified before the domain name
- `href` - the entire URL
- `origin` - `protocol://hostname:port`
- `host` - `hostname:port`